# Match utterances with range of words prior to question tag

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector `tags` with question tags and `tst` utterances in conversation ending on question tags:

```
tags <- c("are you", "are they", "aren't they", "aren't you", "can I", 
"can't ya", "can't you", "could he", "could she", "could you", 
"could they", "didn't it", "didn't you", "didn't we", "didn't she", 
"didn't they", "did he", "did she", "did you", "do I", "do we", 
"do you", "do they", "do you know what I mean", "you know what I mean", 
"does it", "does he", "does she", "doesn't he", "doesn't she", 
"doesn't it", "dunnit", "don't ya", "don't you", "don't they", 
"has he", "has it", "hasn't he", "hasn't she", "have I", "have you", 
"have they", "haven't they", "haven't you", "haven't we", "huh", 
"innit", "is it", "is he", "is she", "is there", "isn't he", 
"isn't it", "isn't it sweetheart", "isn't she", "isn't there", 
"might'n we", "should you", "shouldn't you", "was it", "wasn't she", 
"wasn't he", "was she", "was he", "wasn't it", "weren't they", 
"will he", "will she", "will it", "will there", "will they", 
"would he", "would she", "would ya", "would you", "wouldn't you", 
"wouldn't it", "wouldn't they", "wouldn't she", "wouldn't he", 
"wouldn't you", "won't it", "won't you", "won't they", "won't he", 
"won't she", "won't we", "you know", "you think", "ain't they", 
"don't we", "did i")

tst <- c("It's nice that length isn't it?",            # 4 words prior to question tag
         "that wee boy sleepwalks, doesn't he?",       # 4 words
         "well you know?",                             # 1 word     
         "Sandy Row's isn't it?",                      # 2 words      <-- should match
         "Good this week, innit?",                     # 3 words      <-- should match
         "in front of witnesses, don't you")           # 4 words
```

I need to **match those utterances where the question tag is preceded by exactly 2-3 words**. I've defined this pattern:

```
patt_tag <- paste0(".*(?:\\S+[\\s,.!?]){2,3}\\b(", paste0(tags, collapse = "|"), ")\\b(\\.|\\?|!|,)?$")
```

but it matches utterances it should not match:

```
tst[grepl(patt_tag, tst, perl = T)]
[1] "It's nice that length isn't it?"      "that wee boy sleepwalks, doesn't he?" "Sandy Row's isn't it?"               
[4] "Good this week, innit?"               "in front of witnesses, don't you"
```

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
"Sandy Row's isn't it?" "Good this week, innit?"
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Change the `.*` to `^` in `patt_tag <- paste0(".*(?` .... -> `patt_tag <- paste0("^(?` ...

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed myself! If you want to post this as an answer, do so. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.*` to `^` in `patt_tag <- paste0(".*(?` .... -> `patt_tag <- paste0("^(?` ...

```
patt_tag <- paste0("^(?:\\S+[\\s,.!?]){2,3}\\b(", paste0(tags, collapse = "|"), ")\\b(\\.|\\?|!|,)?$")
tst[grepl(patt_tag, tst, perl = T)]
#[1] "Sandy Row's isn't it?"  "Good this week, innit?"
```